# Which filesystem to backup is the best?

Tags: filesystems, backup, ext4

I just bought a disk to backup all my documents and to store it apart and I don't know what is the filesystem under Linux that gave me better reliability. Maybe I'll backup one time each month and it will not be connected all the time, but I want to be sure that my data will remain.

Maybe ext4?

Comment: No specific file system will make your data disappear while the disk is disconnected, so that's a non-requirement. (The media itself may still fail, but then the file system won't help you much.) This question might be answerable if you state your requirements, *such as* the backup disk size, maximum file size you need to backup, number of files and any specific file system features needed (hardlinks, ACLs, extended attributes, ...). Also [as pointed out](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85970/2465) it may be very well worth your while to consider a file system other than that on the main disk.

Answer (score 7):

The question is subjective.

EXT4 is considered stable and supports journaling (as does EXT3 but not EXT2) which helps with corruption.

[BTRFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Btrfs) is still experimental but offers a lot more features.

[Reiser4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reiser4), [TUX3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tux3), [XFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xfs), [various ZFS implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zfs#Linux), etc. [there is a lot of options](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_filesystems).

Personally, I use EXT4 on all my drives and haven't had issues with the FS.

I'm not aware of any stability benchmarks (there may be some 'white papers' though) but Phoronix has [performance benchmarks](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux_39_fs&num=2)

Lastly, this question may be a duplicate of [Rock-stable filesystem for large files (backups) for linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1430/rock-stable-filesystem-for-large-files-backups-for-linux)

Comment: to note modern (post 2012) `ext4` does [checksums](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Checksums) on *most but not all* metadata , and sadly not the actual on file contents data (which BTRFS, or ZFS does). Also some parts the stable (as in does not change anymore and code base is well tested) on disk layout of `ext4` is redundant as I displayed https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499668/24394, but most data is not. If `ext4` is used as backup, consider increasing its "recoverability" via `e2image` tool!

Comment: Since the answers suggestion `ext4` does not neither provide checksum nor increased protective redundancy measures for the files it stores, it would be advisable to invest to compute - at least very important files in the backup fs - `par2`/`parchive` files, which would provide verificability and repariability (to some extent) and protect against  unreadable sectors occuring, by adding a variable (by default 5%) additional Reed-Solomon redundancy data to those files. This would protect against "silent corruption" and "noticable" [bit rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rot).

Comment: @humanityANDpeace: COuld you provide a link to further information about this?

Answer (score 7):

I always take a different FS for the backup drive than on the main drive just because if I hit a strange FS bug I won't hit it on my backup medium as well.

Comment: Could you please explain what kind of strange FS bug you were thinking of? (Ideally with an historic example which could have affected a backup drive, too)

Comment: Well, normally you don't copy the file system, but the files. This means you just transmit the data, and the files are actually created again in the target file system. This way "FS bugs" don't play any role. Only if you backup the file system as a whole (e.g. dump it with `dd`), you will actually copy your "FS bugs". But then, you normally don't bother about the target file system and dump the copy to the hard drive partition directly.

Comment: @RKiselev yes and no. You still have some advantages/disadvantages with different files systems, like HFS+ getting corrupted out of no where and other file systems that support checksumming it's files (other just the metadata), so it's not a bad idea to have different fs

Comment: @RKiselev Or APFS just losing files https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k60NvrJnNOY when coping. Which is exactly your named case. There was another bug just couple of days/weeks ago that the file system executed files if they had a specific name. Another FS would have not done that, so FS bugs definitely can bite you, even thought I admit it's very unlikely but since the cost is almost zero two have two drives with different FS I don't see any reason not to do it. (Further different FS have different features, very little FS support for example check summing of files)

Comment: @hashier Are you aware that the video you link to doesn't demonstrate a bug in APFS?

Comment: @Andreas So tell me, what does it show then?

Comment: @hashier First clue, the title: "*macOS* may lose data", not "APFS may lose data". Secondly, if you watch the video you can clearly hear "this is actually a bug in the backend disk images application". A bug in an application that uses APFS doesn't automatically mean it's an APFS bug.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. That was more helpful than your first comment. Even if it doesn't show an APFS bug directly but it still holds true that something like this might bite you on one FS and not on a different one.

Comment: Actually it was helpful; it helped me gauge the situation — I find that helpful on Stackexchange. The video is relevant, it has me a bit more worried about that my networked Time machine backups are in sparsebundles, even if they're HFS+.