# Can ext4 filesystem withstand a bad sector (unreadable)?

Tags: ext4, data-recovery, block-device

If a hdd bad sector happens in the metadata for `/home/user/me` on an `ext4` fs would that mean data loss for all subdirectories?

*Background:*
I know that many users are satisfied with the ext4 filesystem, and are even reluctant to change to more "recently" developed alternatives (e.g. BTRFS), claiming increased risk of data loss. Indeed when regarding the time the code for ext4 is around today some results to find [bugs speak](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/AFL%20filesystem%20fuzzing%2C%20Vault%202016_0.pdf).

With this introduction, my question is:

What is the resistence that `ext4` filesystem has against a bad sector from a block device. A bad sector could swallow 4K bytes, which I imagine to "wreak havoc" if those 4K happen to swallow some directory information high up in the direcotry structure (i.e. `/home/user/me` directory).

I am aware that superblocks (being even more basic source of information are kept in a redundant form in ext4, so I imaging a bad block would be repairable there, I am though unsure if it would be automatically dedected)

So my question: **Can ext4 resists loosing Bad block in its meta data?**

I am aware that a bad block in the data/files content will always mean loosing those 512/4K sector (however I am using parchive as a remedy there).

Comment: Not really answering your question, but this is why one should _always_ have backups.

Comment: @roaima it is the fs I use for my backups. I opted against anything not long-long-time tested "new" like BTRFS and took `ext4` because "it must be good, and tested being around for quite some time". So it is my backups I worry about.

Answer (score 7):

After some investigation into the matter *"if `ext4` can handle a read error from a block devices"* my preliminary conclusion is: **only partially redundance exists in ext4**

Here are some findings of my "look into" `ext4`'s "safety featurs" (based on [Ext4 wiki](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout) and 
["Inode Structure in EXT4 filesystem"](https://selvamvasu.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/inode-vs-ext4/) )

- with few exception cases such as [inline Data](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inline_Data) or [inline Data](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Inline_Data2) `ext4` stores file contents "data blocks" and filesystem "meta-data blocks" separately. To the best of my understanding `ext4` takes only provisions for some repair/redundancy with regards to latter.
- repair/reduncany of metadata relies on a) a 2010 newly introduced/added [checksum feature](https://ext4.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Ext4_Disk_Layout#Checksums) and b) of having additional copies of **crucial meta-data**
- such "**crucial meta-data**" (in the sense of being at different parts of the block device) is.

  1. the `ext4` superblock
  2. the `block group descriptors` information.
- **checksums** protect the superblock, multiple-mount-protection, extented attributes, Directory Entries, HTREE nodes, Extents, Inodes and Group descriptors. While extents (a new `ext4` feature is hence protected that supercedes in part the older Indirect Block Addressing (IBA) ), the older IBA blocks are not, as is stated:

  > Notice that there is neither a magic number nor a checksum to provide any level of confidence that the [IBA] block isn't full of garbage.

## What ext4 can hence recover from on unreadable disc sector (512/4K)

- Loss of *Superblock* and *Block Group Descriptors*, which have redundant copies stored in either all/or some specific Block Groups on disk.
- Loss of a directory entry, becuase of an unreadable sector does not imply loss of access and moreover content of the files stored in the directory (only their names are lost). The files (including subdirectories) remain accessible via their `filespec` `<inode-number>` in `debuge2fs`.
- Loss of parts of the `inode table`. Each entry in the *inode table* (the table being split up and the parts being writen into the Block groups that form the `ext4` disk layout) occupies (padded) 256 bytes. Hence a unreadable sector should mean the loss of 2 to 16 files only. Additionally With the **checksum** features any corruption within the inode table should be if not necessarily correctable, however not go unnotices.

## What are bad sector induced troubles `ext4` seems not to protect against

- not crucial metadata, including inodes, directory entries, extents, IBA is not protected.
- *inodes*: As mentioned the inode taking 256byte and being the core handle to the blocks that make up the file data, means loosing acccess to 2 up to 16 files (mostly irrespective of their file size).
- *directory entries:* if lost due to a bad sector, imply that the file-paths to all files inside will have the filename portion lost. The size of the bad sector 512 or 4K bytes on the one hand and the filenames and space taken by the directory hashing feature impact the extent of the loss. Also it is my understanding that directory hashing essentially provides a redundancy (but I cannot assure this).
- extents: lost parts of information in extent trees, alike the loss of the inode itself will compromise the acccess to the data blocks making up the file's content and would hence mean roughly the loss of 1 file.
- IBA blocks: (see extents) + as mentioned earlier will additionally suffer increased vulnerability also to partial curruption (which however was not the main focus of the question).

## additionally methods used

in order to test and prove some of the enumerated challenges with the `ext4` disk layout (in regards to its resistance to bad sectors) the following tools are handy

- `debugfs <blockdev>` which allows accessing files via filespec (either filepath, or in case of problems via inode number in `< >`)
- `truncate`, `dd`,`losetup`,`mount` and `mkfs.ext4` to create `ext4` filesystems to play with.
- `dumpe2fs`,`tune2fs` which provide information
- `dm-setup` to assemble a virtual block device simulating a read error like this:

  ```
  $> dmsetup create badsectordevice << EOF
  0 2902 linear /dev/loop1 0
  2902 2 error
  2904 17576 linear /dev/loop1 2904
  EOF
  ```

  where as the exmample shows the block device sector is 512 and `ext4` block size is 1024 hence and hence the LBA sector 2902,2903 are unreadable.